# Get Data in "if" condition laravel

Tags: laravel

So basic I have two tables "Accounts" and "Characters" that are linked by a single ID
Each "Account" has 3 "Characters"
So I want to display the 3 characters that are linked to the main "Account"

this is my HomeController

```
    {

       $data = DB::table('characters')
            ->join('accounts', 'accounts.cUid', '=','characters.pUniqueID')->get();
        return view('home', compact('data'));
    }
```

this is my Home.Blade

```
@foreach($data as $per)
            @if( $per->pUniqueID == Auth::user()->cUid )
....
....
         @else
       <script>window.location.href = '{{url("/characters")}}'; </script>
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: use a var_dump($data); before your loop @foreach, and post a revelant part of what is displayed, you can use var_dump($per) inside loop to see what you got on each $per

Comment: do you have any relationships set up in the models?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the relationships in your model:

**Accounts.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Accounts extends Model
{
    public function characters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Characters');
    }
}
```

So, in your query:

```
$data = Accounts::with("characters")->get();

return view('home', compact('data'));
```

And in your template:

```
@foreach($data as $per)
    @if($per->pUniqueID == Auth::user()->cUid)
        @foreach($per->characters as $character)
            {{$character->id}} //or any other character attribute
        @endforeach
    @else
       <script>window.location.href = '{{url("/characters")}}'; </script>
    @endif
@endforeach
```